Show that a geometrically normal scheme of finite type has singular locus of codimension at least 2.
I am trying to prove that a geometrically normal scheme of finite type over a field $k$ has singular locus of codimension at least 2. So far, I written the following argument to prove the result in the case that $k = \overline{k}$:
If the local ring at a point $x$ is dimension $0$, it is a field, which is regular. If the local ring is dimension $1$, then is also regular since any integrally closed local domain of dimension $1$ is regular by commutative algebra. If $x$ is a closed point, then since $k = \overline{k}$, we can conclude that $x$ is a smooth point. This shows that the set of closed singular points has codimension $\geq 2$.
Now, since the set of closed points is very dense in $X$, there is a bijection between the closed subsets of the set of irreducible points and $X$ itself in which irreducible closed sets correspond to irreducible closed sets. It follows that since the set of closed singular points has codimension $\geq 2$, so does $X_{\mathrm{sing}}$.
I am stuck on how to reduce to the algebraically closed case. If $X$ is geometrically normal, then $X \otimes_{k} \overline{k}$ is normal, and by the argument above, it has singular locus of codimension $\geq 2$. I know that the projection $X \otimes_{k} \overline{k} \to X$ sends singular points to singular points, but I am not sure if it sends smooth points to smooth points, and so I am not sure how to get a handle on the codimension of $X_{\mathrm{sing}}$, since there may be singular points that do not lie under a singular point of $X \otimes_{k} \overline{k}$. How can I proceed?
